# Push nuget package from visual studio to devops artifact

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, nuget, nuget-package, azure-artifacts

I'm trying to automate the push of a nuget package from Visual Studio to Azure Devops Artifact when I'm build the solution.
I'm able to do that utomatically on my local nuget repository, but I'm not able to do it on my Azure repo. It fails with a 401 (unathorized) because I cannot put credentials on the command and the VS credential are not used.
To automate the publishing Ive set this command on the project file:

```
  <Target Name="NugetAdd" AfterTargets="Pack">
    <exec command="nuget add $(OutputPath)$(PackageId).$(PackageVersion).nupkg -source d:\NuGetLocal" />    
    <exec command="nuget push -source MyAzureRepo -ApiKey VSTS $(OutputPath)$(PackageId).$(PackageVersion).nupkg" />    
  </Target>
```

The first command is executed successfully, and the second fails because credential are requested. If I run the command in a powershell it runs without problem, asking for credentials.
There is a way to make it working?

Comment: Not as an answer to your question, but my preference is usually to have a pipeline configured that handle the versioning/publishing instead of managing that on a local machine.  You might have an easier time with the credentials and authentication if you setup a CI trigger on a master/main branch check-in instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved by giving the command

nuget sources update -Name MyAzureRepo -Source https://my.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/MyAzureRepo/nuget/v3/index.json -username user@user.com -password PAT

After that the command it's working everytime I build the solution.

The solution by Levi Lu-MSFT does not fit my needs because I want update nuget repository only when I decide to increment the version.

Answer (score 0):

You can try putting the credentials of your azure artifacts feed in your nuget.config file.

First you need to generate a [Personal access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page) from Azure devops with the **Read&Write Packaging** scope.

Then you can provide the credentials to the azure feed for your nuget source. See below example:

```
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="AzureArtifactFeedName" value="https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/org/_packaging/AzureArtifactFeedName/nuget/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
  <packageSourceCredentials>
    <AzureArtifactFeedName>
        <add key="Username" value="any" />
        <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="{Personal Access Token}" />
      </AzureArtifactFeedName>
  </packageSourceCredentials>
</configuration>
```

You can also run below commands to add the feed credential:

```
sources Add -Name "AzureArtifactFeedName" -Source "https://my.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/AzureArtifactFeedName/nuget/v3/index.json" -username any -password PersonalAccessToken -ConfigFile path/to/Nuget.config -StorePasswordInClearText
```

Then the package can be automatically pushed.

Above solution may cause security concern, for it explicitly writes the PAT in the nuget.config file.

Using an Azure pipeline to automatically pack and push your package(using [NuGet task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/nuget?view=azure-devops) to run `pack` and `push` commands) may be a better workaround.

See [document here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/nuget?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) for more information.